PySimpleGUI personalized icon disappear if run the .exe on another PC (pyinstaller)
I didn't find anything like my problem already posted.
I did an application using PySimpleGUI and to realize the .exe i used pyinstaller and used the --icon command using both the image .ico address in local and also the simple icon_name.ico but the problem is that if i run the application on myPC i can see the correct icon on each windows of the application, instead if i export the .exe on another PC PySimpleGUI show me its original icon.
Had it happened to someone else? How did you resolve this issue?
I would like to write directly to PySimpleGUI company but i didn't find any contact to write to.

There's an issue opened on the PSG GitHub that explains this and ways through it.  Do a search and you'll find a lot of info. Or, open an issue there about it and someone will be happy to help.  Seeing the PSG logo means your application didn't set one.  Lots of ways fix your problem.

To set one icon for all windows in the app....
https://docs.pysimplegui.com/en/latest/call_reference/tkinter/functions/configuration/

This is where you'll find the information I was referring to:  https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/6655
You can reach the PSG team via GitHub issues.

After import into the script, use:
sg.set_global_icon(icon_file_name.ico)

and remember to include the icon file into the "dist" folder.
In this way when you execute the file on other PC it will work perfectly, showing the setted icon on each window of the software.

Did you have the .ico file on the 2nd pc too?
How did you made the .exe file?
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico app.py


this doesn't work i tried it before posting the issue, thanks in anycase :(

If you see the default PySimpleGUI icon on the taskbar, then you're not setting it in your PySimpleGUI program.
This example sets an icon that will be used for ALL windows, both user created and pre-made like popups.
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def main():
    sg.set_global_icon(icon())

    sg.popup_scrolled('A popup', non_blocking=True)
    sg.popup('Another popup')


def icon():
    return b'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'


main()

On the taskbar I see:

And the 2 windows created look like this:

They are all using a PNG image that was Base64 encoded and put into the code.  You can do this easily using the psgresizer program.
